# Internal Server Error-Python on HostGator

Tags: python, server

I am trying to run a simple python script on Hostgator. I have saved that file in the cgi-bin directory. Whenever I try to load the file on the web browser it throws an Internal Server Error. I tried the following to resolve it but it did not work

1. Set File Permissions to 755
2. Tried testing by using hello.py and hello.cgi both throw the same error
3. Created .htaccess file on Document Root and added the line **Addhandler cgi-script .py .pl .cgi**
4. Added this on the file hello.py  #!/usr/bin/python
5. Tried to check the error log in cpanel but for some reason it is empty.

This is my file

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print()

print("Hello World!")
```

Kindly suggest on how could the Issue be resolved

Comment: CGI is about the last way I'd want to run Python on the web in 2016. Do you have to use HostGator for this?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes as part of a project, I have to use HostGator

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Is there a better way to run it? I am new to this field (Python)

Comment: I guess it depends on your plan. Ask HostGator support. The best way is uwsgi, but they don't have an implementation for that. I believe you're stuck with either Apache `mod_python` (yuck) or CGI (even worse). If you're on a VPS I think you can set up uwsgi, but you have to do all the work yourself.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist My whole purpose of using an external web host is to access or consume an API coded in Python. Can you suggest the best way to do it?

Comment: If you're not restricted to HostGator, I'd pick a different web host that's more friendly to Python. HostGator is really better suited to PHP. Take a look at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) or similar projects that have better Python support for the web.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Those are really cool. I would definitely try it . Thanks for letting me know. By the way I know someone who has a web host called "Site5". Now is that better or worse than Hostgator?

Comment: Sorry, never used it. I used to use HostGator until I started making Python apps, then I started using Heroku. I've only heard of OpenShift on here.